# Restrict user to use only network provided time in react native

Tags: react-native

I have an attendance app in react native, in which I want to restrict employees to use only network provided time so that employees won't be able to tamper the date and time.

Is there any option or solution to implement this in android and iOS as well?

The App works in both Offline and Online mode.

Are there any libraries available to do this?